# Run subroutine when Workbook finishes loading?

Tags: vba, excel

**Scope**

I am working on automatically generating some Excel reports via C#. The problem is that, when it comes to "Features", my support library [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) doesn't cover it all.

**Solution**

Since i know that VBA has support for everything i need to do on Excel Files, i decided to use it in order to accomplish everything i can't in C#. So here's my current flow for generating the report

1 - Setup a "Template" excel file (containing all the VBA code i need, configured into the `Workbook_Open` event, so that they will run as soon as the person opens the excel document)

2 - Run my C# code to open the template, fill it with data, generate pivot tables, charts and so forth

3 - Save it with a different name, to avoid overriding the Template file

By doing so, i end up having a report that is ready to "Trigger" my macro as soon as someone opens it. The macro wil do things such as Creation of Pivot Charts, Auto selecting filters of the pivots and so forth. Nothing too fancy.

**Problem:**

When i manually open the Excel file, the macro does not work, raising this error:

[image: Funky Excel Error]

On this line of code

[image: Not a fancy line of code]

But, when i wait for the document to stop loading, then manually executes the macro, it works just as expected.

I think that the cause might be related to the data not being "ready" to be read once the `Workbook_Open` event Triggers.

Comment: At this point in execution, does `ActiveSheet` contain the pivot table specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never encountered this quite like that but I have encountered it very similarly when using HTML Objects. Not sure if this will work but it's worth a shot

```
Do Until Application.Ready = True
DoEvents: Loop
```

Comment: Awesome, that was a stab in the dark. I have used ie.Ready_State before but never Application.Ready

Answer (score 3):

Try the `Workbook_Activate` event which happens after `Workbook_Open`, and the Pivot Table(s), etc., can be referred to.

Otherwise, if it is necessary to cause a delay, you can use the `OnTime` method:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "my_Procedure"
```

Put this in the Open event and it will run the procedure named my_Procedure after a 2 second delay.

Comment: I will give it a try. I tried Application.Wait but it failed. Maybe, the OnTime will work. I will be back soon with a feedback

Comment: Can "My_Procedure" be a Sub ?

Comment: Yes, it has to be. Put it in a standard Module.

Comment: I was getting an error with the Sub being in the Workbook vba file. It worked once it is on a separated module. I will try that now